# can I access the original corpus used to train the Stanford NER Chinese model

Tags: stanford-nlp

I am trying to retrain the Chinese model of Stanford Name Entity Recognizer. I wonder if there is a way to get the original Chinese corpus for training the official model? The stanford-nlp web page says that they used corpus from CoNLL, MUC-6, MUC-7 and ACE. I checked that CoNLL2003 does not seem to have Chinese corpus and I need to pay for MUC-6, MUC-7 and ACE. Are there other ways to get those? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The web page info is for English not Chinese. For Chinese, I believe it's using the OntoNotes corpus - perhaps check the corresponding research papers. At any rate, we can't distribute these corpora, you have to get them from [LDC](https://www.ldc.upenn.edu/).